# how do i add database name with hyphen character using script in ubuntu

Tags: mysql, database, bash, shell, terminal

I've tried using this code in a script but it just created what is inside the backtick. In this example, "echo "table-db"" was created in the database. It didn't create the name of the folder with the hyphen character in the query

```
hyph=`ls -l $DBDIR | egrep '^d' | grep '.-.' | awk '{print $9}'`

dbhype=($hyph)


for dbtry in ${!dbhype[*]}
   do            
        mysql -u$dbUser -p$dbPass -e 'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `echo "table-db"` CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci';

        echo "Database ${dbhype[$dbtry]} created."

done
```

Comment: i tried using "echo "table-db"" in this example because based from what i have searched, backtick would only read commands but i actually want to create the name table-db in this case or the names of the folder in the query.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

In mysql queries table names [may contain](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html) alphanumeric characters, underscore and dollar sign. In order to be able to use other ANSI characters you must place names in single backquotes.

```
`table-db`
```

But in bash they have different meaning and used for [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html). In bash there are also several types of strings -- in double quotes and in single quotes. The difference between them is that in double quotes variable expansion and command substitution are performed, while in single quotes they don't. So you can use backquotes with mysql semantics within single quotes as is

```
mysql -e 'CREATE DATABASE `table-db`;'
```

but must escape them when using within double quotes, so that they wouldn't be interpreted by bash as command sustitution.

```
mysql -e "CREATE DATABASE \`table-db\`;"
```

As you want to get the database name from variable you need to place it beyond single quote strings, like that:

```
mysql -e "CREATE DATABASE \`$dbname\`;"
```

or like that:

```
mysql -e 'CREATE DATABASE `'$dbname'`;'
```

Comment: thank you for this answer user2683246 but i also tried this one. But it only created just one database. Only the table-db. How about the other names in the query, eg: table-db2, table-db3, table-db4 and etc... Can I not put a variable inside a backtick symbol? I want to put the variable "${dbhype[$dbtry]}" inside the backtick symbol but when i run the script, only ${dbhype[$dbtry]} was created as a database name and not the names of the folders in my query

Comment: Within single quotes variables do not expanded by the shell. Use double quotes.

Comment: thank you @user2683246 for the idea. I edited my code with this one and now it worked! :)



hyph=`ls -l $DBDIR | egrep '^d' | grep '.-.' | awk '{print $9}'`


dbhype=($hyph)
          for dbtry in ${!dbhype[*]}
              do            
                  mysql -u$dbUser -p$dbPass -e 'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `'${dbhype[$dbtry]}'` CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;'
                  echo "Database ${dbhype[$dbtry]} created."
          done